# Angular 4 custom validator not working for select tag

Tags: angular, forms, custom-validators

i have two forms in two different modals and i'm applying custom validator on Foreign Currency which is a dropdown , validator compare the selected value with another dropdown that is Base Currency if the values are same displays error.
it works fine on createTradeForm but doesnot work on tradeEdit form

Here is createTradeForm in html template

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <form  [formGroup]="createTradeEntryForm" class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" enctype="multipart/form-data" ngnativevalidate="" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Trade Entry</h4>
                    <button aria-label="Close" class="close" type="button" (click)="TradeEntryVm.hide()">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">   
                    <div class="card-block">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="BaseCurrency">Currency 1</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <select formControlName="BaseCurrency" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" size ="1"  id="BaseCurrency" name="BaseCurrency" ng-reflect-required="required" ng-reflect-name="Base Currency">
                                        <option [selected]="true" disabled="" value="0" ng-reflect-value="0">Please select</option>
                                        <option value="1" ng-reflect-value="1">USD</option>
                                        <option value="2" ng-reflect-value="2">NZD</option>
                                        <option value="3" ng-reflect-value="3">AUD</option>
                                        <option value="4" ng-reflect-value="4">ZAR</option>
                                        <option value="5" ng-reflect-value="5">CHF</option>
                                        <option value="6" ng-reflect-value="6">CAD</option>
                                        <option value="7" ng-reflect-value="7">EUR</option>
                                        <option value="8" ng-reflect-value="8">GBP</option>
                                        <option value="9" ng-reflect-value="9">SGD</option>
                                        <option value="10" ng-reflect-value="10">ILS</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="ForeignCurrency">Currency 2</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <select formControlName="ForeignCurrency" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" id="ForeignCurrency" name="ForeignCurrency" ng-reflect-required="required" ng-reflect-name="ForeignCurrency" >
                                        <option [selected]="true" disabled="" value="0" ng-reflect-value="0">Please select</option>
                                        <option value="1" ng-reflect-value="1">USD</option>
                                        <option value="2" ng-reflect-value="2">NZD</option>
                                        <option value="3" ng-reflect-value="3">AUD</option>
                                        <option value="4" ng-reflect-value="4">ZAR</option>
                                        <option value="5" ng-reflect-value="5">CHF</option>
                                        <option value="6" ng-reflect-value="6">CAD</option>
                                        <option value="7" ng-reflect-value="7">EUR</option>
                                        <option value="8" ng-reflect-value="8">GBP</option>
                                        <option value="9" ng-reflect-value="9">SGD</option>
                                        <option value="10" ng-reflect-value="10">ILS</option>
                                    </select>    
                                    <em *ngIf="ForeignCurrency.invalid && ForeignCurrency.dirty">Selected currency should be different from Base Currency!</em>
                                </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

and here is My tradeEdit form in html Template

```
                <form [formGroup]="tradeEditForm"  class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-invalid" enctype="multipart/form-data" ngnativevalidate="" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Trade</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="editModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body"> 
                        <div class="card-block" >

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="BaseCurrency">Currency 1</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <select formControlName="BaseCurrency" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" size ="1"  id="BaseCurrencyEdit" name="BaseCurrency" ng-reflect-required="required" ng-reflect-name="Base Currency">
                                            <option [selected]="true" disabled="" value="0" ng-reflect-value="0">Please select</option>
                                            <option value="1" ng-reflect-value="1">USD</option>
                                            <option value="2" ng-reflect-value="2">NZD</option>
                                            <option value="3" ng-reflect-value="3">AUD</option>
                                            <option value="4" ng-reflect-value="4">ZAR</option>
                                            <option value="5" ng-reflect-value="5">CHF</option>
                                            <option value="6" ng-reflect-value="6">CAD</option>
                                            <option value="7" ng-reflect-value="7">EUR</option>
                                            <option value="8" ng-reflect-value="8">GBP</option>
                                            <option value="9" ng-reflect-value="9">SGD</option>
                                            <option value="10" ng-reflect-value="10">ILS</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="ForeignCurrency">Currency 2</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <select formControlName="ForeignCurrency" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" id="ForeignCurrencyEdit" name="ForeignCurrency" ng-reflect-required="required" ng-reflect-name="ForeignCurrency" >
                                            <option [selected]="true" disabled="" value="0" ng-reflect-value="0">Please select</option>
                                            <option value="1" ng-reflect-value="1">USD</option>
                                            <option value="2" ng-reflect-value="2">NZD</option>
                                            <option value="3" ng-reflect-value="3">AUD</option>
                                            <option value="4" ng-reflect-value="4">ZAR</option>
                                            <option value="5" ng-reflect-value="5">CHF</option>
                                            <option value="6" ng-reflect-value="6">CAD</option>
                                            <option value="7" ng-reflect-value="7">EUR</option>
                                            <option value="8" ng-reflect-value="8">GBP</option>
                                            <option value="9" ng-reflect-value="9">SGD</option>
                                            <option value="10" ng-reflect-value="10">ILS</option>
                                        </select>    
                                        <em *ngIf="tradeEditForm.controls.ForeignCurrency.invalid && tradeEditForm.controls.ForeignCurrency.dirty">Selected currency should be different from Base Currency!</em>
                                        for curr dir: {{tradeEditForm.controls.ForeignCurrency.dirty}} <br>
                                        for inva cur: {{tradeEditForm.controls.ForeignCurrency.invalid}}
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and here is the component

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { DatepickerOptions } from 'ng2-datepicker';
toaster/angular2-toaster';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/modal';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'trade-entry.component.html',
  })
export class TradesComponent
 {
    InitilizeForm(): any {
      this.BaseCurrency =  new FormControl('',Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(".*\\S.*")]))
      this.ForeignCurrency =  new FormControl('',Validators.compose([SameCurrencyValidator("BaseCurrency"), Validators.pattern(".*\\S.*") ]))

      this.createTradeEntryForm = new FormGroup({
        // BlotterId: new FormControl(),
        AccountNo: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
        Type: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        MarketRate:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
        BaseCurrencyAmount: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        BaseCurrency: this.BaseCurrency,
        ForeignCurrencyAmount: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        ForeignCurrency: this.ForeignCurrency,
        TradeDate:new FormControl(),
        SettlementDate: new FormControl(),
        // Status: new FormControl(),
        Comment:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
      })
    }
    InitilizeFormEdit(): any {
      this.BaseCurrencyEdit =  new FormControl('',Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(".*\\S.*")]))
      this.ForeignCurrencyEdit=  new FormControl('',Validators.compose([Validators.required, SameCurrencyValidatorEdit("BaseCurrency")]))
      this.tradeEditForm = new FormGroup({
        BlotterId: new FormControl(),
        AccountNo: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        TradeDate:new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        Type: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        MarketRate:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
        BaseCurrencyAmount: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        BaseCurrency: this.BaseCurrencyEdit,
        ForeignCurrencyAmount: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        ForeignCurrency: this.ForeignCurrencyEdit,
        SettlementDate: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        // Status: new FormControl(),
        Comment:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
        // Status23: new FormControl(),

      })
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.InitilizeForm()
      this.InitilizeFormEdit()

      // this.tradesEntries=this.tradesEntrySerive.getEntries();
      this.LoggedinUser = this.authService.getCurrentUser()
      this.searchObjectHeader.UserRefId = this.LoggedinUser.UserRefId
      this.tradeDate=new Date()
      this.settlementDate =new Date()
      // this.tradesEntries=this.tradesEntrySerive.getEntries()

      this.getPage(1);

    }
      @ViewChild('TradeEntryVm') public TradeEntryVm: ModalDirective;
      @ViewChild('editModal') public EditModal: ModalDirective;
      @ViewChild('deleteModal') public DeleteModal:ModalDirective;
      @ViewChild('executeModal') public ExecuteModal:ModalDirective;
      p: number = 1;
      firstpage: number = 1;
      total: number;
      searchObjectHeader = {
        SherpaClientId: 0,
        UserType: 0,
        UserId: 0,
        UserRole:0,
        UserRefId:0,
        'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      }
      searchObjectBody = {
        PageSize: 0,
        PageNumber: 0,
        TotalPages:100,
        TotalRecord:0,
        Text: ''
      }

      EditfromList(ob: any) {      this.getAccountList=this.accountService.getAllTradeAccounts(this.searchObjectHeader, this.searchObjectBody)
        .do(res => {
          if(res.Status==0)
          {
            this.toastSErvice.pop('error', 'Error', res.Error) 
            this.spinnerloading=false;       
          }
          else
        {
          if(res.Data.length==0)
          {
             this.emptyChk =true;
          }
          console.log(res)
        }
        })
        .map(res => res.Data);
        this.marketRate=ob.MarketRate
        this.offerAmount=ob.ForeignCurrencyAmount
        this.baseAmount=ob.BaseCurrencyAmount
        this.tradeDateEdit=ob.TradeDate
        this.settlementDateEdit=ob.SettlementDate
        console.log("foreign currency"+ ob.ForeignCurrency)
        this.tradeEditForm = this.fb.group({
          BlotterId: [ob.BlotterId],
          AccountNo: [ob.AccountNo],
          TradeDate:[ob.TradeDate],
          Type: [ob.Type],
          MarketRate:[ob.MarketRate],
          BaseCurrencyAmount: [ob.BaseCurrencyAmount],
          BaseCurrency: [ob.BaseCurrency],
          ForeignCurrencyAmount: [ob.ForeignCurrencyAmount],
          ForeignCurrency: [ob.ForeignCurrency],
          SettlementDate: [ob.SettlementDate],
          // Status:[ob.Status],
          Comment:[ob.Comment]
        })
      }
```

and here is the createTrade form custom validator for foreignCurrency

```
    import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';


export function SameCurrencyValidator (otherControlName: string) {

  let thisControl: FormControl;
  let otherControl: FormControl;

  return function SameCurrencyValidate (control: FormControl) {

    if (!control.parent) {
      return null;
    }

    // Initializing the validator.
    if (!thisControl) {
      thisControl = control;
      otherControl = control.parent.get(otherControlName) as FormControl;
      if (!otherControl) {
        throw new Error('SameCurrencyValidator(): other control is not found in parent group');
      }
      otherControl.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
        thisControl.updateValueAndValidity();
      });
    }

    if (!otherControl) {
      return null;
    }

    if (otherControl.value === thisControl.value) {
      return {
        matchOther: true
      };
    }

    return null;

  }

}
```

and here is my editTradeForm custom validator for foreidgn currency

```
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';


export function SameCurrencyValidatorEdit (otherControlName: string) {

  let thisControl: FormControl;
  let otherControl: FormControl;

  return function SameCurrencyValidateEdit (control: FormControl) {

    if (!control.parent) {
      return null;
    }

    // Initializing the validator.
    if (!thisControl) {
      thisControl = control;
      otherControl = control.parent.get(otherControlName) as FormControl;
      console.log(control.parent)
      if (!otherControl) {
        throw new Error('SameCurrencyValidatorEdit(): other control is not found in parent group');
      }
      otherControl.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
        thisControl.updateValueAndValidity();
      });
    }

    if (!otherControl) {
      return null;
    }

    if (otherControl.value === thisControl.value) {
      var check = otherControl.value === thisControl.value
      console.log(check)
      return {
        matchOther: true
      };
    }

    return null;

  }

}
```

Comment: Try to clean the code post. add an explication of the code and try to not put to much code.

Comment: sorry for that i'm new to this, now i have cleaned it a bit

Comment: no answer from 5days